# Very new to python, wanting to add a new column named ‘Total’, which is the sum of other totals

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['Total']= df.iloc[3:5].sum(axis=1)
```

returns NaN for some most values, why is this? They are all intergers.

[image: pic of df.head, also shows incorrect addition? is is also adding generation column?]

Also is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with add with columns slice

```
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:, 3:5].sum(axis=1)
```